# Running python script from R and getting the returned output?

Tags: python, r, pandas, shiny

I am writing an app that would run on the server and using R shiny for front end(because it's going to be very simple and shiny is enough) and python for backend. 
I need to call python script from R passing item id as a parameter, so I thought it would be easy to do this if I  called python script using system comands:

```
system('"python script.py 6548796"')
```

But how do I take the output of that script back to my R program..?
The program would return a dataframe that I would use in R to print out the table and do some text formating when displaying...

Comment: have you seen the [`reticulate` package](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)?

Comment: @SamMason I believe that this is not an option for me, because other people will be working with the same output using python, I am the crazy one using R for my app GUI...

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar application while ago where I wanted to execute multiple scripts such as .py and .sh from shiny. My suggestion is to create a terminal on shiny app so you can execute it with output.

[Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/a-shiny-app-that-exposes-an-r-terminal/3632/4) is the details for it.